# Doubly Linked List: Deleting all occurrences of a given key

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *rlink;
    struct node *llink;
}NODE;

NODE* insert(NODE* header,int info)
{
    NODE *new,*temp;
    new=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new->data=info;
    new->rlink=NULL;
    new->llink=NULL;
    if(header->rlink==NULL)
    {
      header->rlink=new;
      new->llink=header;
    }
    else
    {
      temp=header->rlink;
      header->rlink=new;
      new->llink=header;
      new->rlink=temp;
      temp->llink=new;
    }
    return header;
}



NODE* delete(NODE* header,int info)
{
    NODE *temp,*pred,*succ;
    temp=header->rlink;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        while(temp!=NULL&&(temp->data!=info))
        {
            pred=temp;
            temp=temp->rlink;
        }
        if(temp->rlink!=NULL)
        {
            temp->rlink->llink=pred;
        }
        if(temp->llink!=NULL)
        {
            pred->rlink=temp->rlink;
        }
        free(temp);
        temp=pred->rlink;
    }

    return header;
}

void main()
{
    int ch,info;
    NODE* header;
    header=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    header->rlink=NULL;
    header->llink=NULL;
    ........
```

The delete function works properly only if the key specified is at the end of the list.

Suppose if the input list is 20 10 20 10 and the key specified is 10, deletion takes place seamlessly but if the key specified is 20, there's a segmentation fault.

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: My suggestion would be to start with the simplest possible case, and when that works, add complexity. So, 1) empty list, 2) single-entry list, 3) two-entry list with/without duplicates, and so on.

Comment: When the key is 20, you are trying to delete the first entry in the list, and the value of pred may not be defined, which would explain the seg fault. Also *succ is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues :

- When you get to this check :

  ```
  if(temp->rlink!=NULL)
  ```

  `temp` could be `NULL` (because the preceding `while` loop has a stop condition of `temp == NULL` - when the last node does not match).

  Dereferencing `NULL` typically causes a segmentation fault.

  If `temp` is `NULL` at that point, just end the loop - you've reached the end of the list without finding more nodes to delete.
- Similarly, when you get to :

  ```
  temp=pred->rlink;
  ```

  `pred` could be uninitialized (if the innermost `while` loop was skipped - when the first node matches).

  Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer can also cause a segmentation fault.

  To avoid that, you could initialize `pred` with `header`.

Comment: I initialized it with header but I'm still getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Legendary : did you read my entire answer ? I listed two things that needed fixing.